# Explain "recitar" in "Vesti la giubba" aria

Tags: word-meaning

Aria "Vesti la giubba" from Ruggero Leoncavallo's opera *Pagliacci* begins with the word "recitar".
It is translated into English as "act". 
If I am not mistaken "recitare" is closer to the English "recite" rather than "act". Also, there is no "recitar" in standard Italian.
It sounds like it should be "recita" if it is second person imperative.
Please explain this word.

Comment: «It is translated into English as...» - By whom?

Comment: Take a look at Wiki

Comment: What do you mean? _You_ are apparently quoting a particular translation. Which one?

Comment: @DaG: I immagine Hank is referring to  [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vesti_la_giubba).

Comment: Thanks, @Charo. My point was that people often says “X translates as Y”, “X is translated Y”, while there is no such thing as an absolute, impersonal translation; every translation is a particular choice of some human being (or, possibly, computer program).

Comment: Of course, @DaG: I completely agree with you.

Answer (score 4):

The verb *recitare* can mean *to act*. Meaning 2 in the [Treccani dictionary entry](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/recitare) says

> Interpretare un’opera teatrale, cinematografica, radiofonica o televisiva, o una parte di un’opera

The form *recitar* is a truncation used, in this case, to fit the metric of the verses.

The character singing the aria, Canio, has just discovered his wife's infidelity, but has to dress as a clown and act notwithstanding his life problems. So he starts off with *Recitare!* (truncated for metric reasons), that can be loosely translated as “Alas! I have to act!”

Comment: @Hank Truncation in this case means that we remove the last vowel, not the last syllable. It is a very common operation in spoken Italian (I at least do it normally when I speak)

Comment: Truncation doesn't make any sense if we are talking about Recita. The writer just added an R to Recita which is not trucation at all.. Is it Act (Recita) or To act (recitare) that is the meaning of Recitar?   Imperative is actually Recita and not Recitare. Even I know this. The writer added the letter R to Recita!

Comment: @Hank The text has “Recitar!”, not “Recita!”. The character (il Pagliaccio) is moaning because he has to act.

Comment: But the correct Italian is Recita.

Comment: @Hank No, definitely not in this case

Comment: @Hank In this case it is a noun, roughly we can translate the beginning as "Acting! While caught by the delirium I don't know what I say or what I do!" (@egreg: small note, the main character's name is Canio, not Pagliaccio, that's his stage name)

Comment: Gerundive? And why would he say/sing " acting!"?

Comment: @Hank He's substantivizing the verb: maybe you could also translate it as "To act!" rather than "acting!". Essentially he's saying out loud the name of the action he's supposed to do now, as if in disbelief that he's really going to do that. If you need more explanations, it'd be better to [move to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11367/bar-sport)

Comment: Thanks. I think I get it now.